# How can we avoid pragma pack warnings from windows headers when using /external compiler options?

Tags: visual-c++, external, compiler-warnings, pragma

Having found https://devblogs.microsoft.com/cppblog/broken-warnings-theory/ we tried it out in the hope of focussing our /Analyze builds on finding problems in our own code. We used `c /analyze /analyze:stacksize131072 /analyze:WX- /experimental:external /external:anglebrackets /external:W0` in our compiler invocations but found this triggered lots of warnings=errors from Windows Kit header files.  e.g. 
`c:\program files (x86)\windows kits\10\include\10.0.17763.0\shared\rpc.h(65): error C2220: warning treated as error - no 'object' file generated
c:\program files (x86)\windows kits\10\include\10.0.17763.0\shared\rpc.h(65): warning C4103: alignment changed after including header, may be due to missing #pragma pack(pop)
c:\program files (x86)\windows kits\10\include\10.0.17763.0\shared\rpc.h(223): warning C4103: alignment changed after including header, may be due to missing #pragma pack(pop)
c:\program files (x86)\windows kits\10\include\10.0.17763.0\shared\rpcndr.h(47): warning C4103: alignment changed after including header, may be due to missing #pragma pack(pop)
c:\program files (x86)\windows kits\10\include\10.0.17763.0\shared\rpcndr.h(3300): warning C4103: alignment changed after including header, may be due to missing #pragma pack(pop)`

How can we avoid these errors? They directly oppose the whole point of the 'external' options.

Comment: https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/t/warning-c4103-in-visual-studio-166-update/1057589